# Is it okay to panic inside defer function, especially when it's already panicking?

Tags: go

```
func sub(){
    defer func (){
        panic(2)
    }()
    panic(1)
}

func main(){
    defer func(){
        x:=recover()
        println(x.(int));
    }()
    sub()
}
```

I tried this code and it seems the first panic `panic(1)` is simply "overwritten" by the second panic `panic(2)`.

But is it okay to do that? Or call a Golang function that might panic inside defer function?

(In C++ it's almost never acceptable to throw exception out of a destructor. It terminates program if stack is already unwinding. I wonder if panicking in a similar manner could be bad in Golang.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's okay. Panicking from a deferred function is not really a new, special state, it just means that the panicking sequence will not stop.

Your example code also proves that it's okay, and even a [`panic()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#panic) called from a deferred function can be stopped by an "upper" level call to [`recover()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#recover).

[Spec: Handling panics:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics)

> Suppose a function `G` defers a function `D` that calls `recover` and a panic occurs in a function on the same goroutine in which `G` is executing. When the running of deferred functions reaches `D`, the return value of `D`'s call to `recover` will be the value passed to the call of panic. **If `D` returns normally, without starting a new panic, the panicking sequence stops.** In that case, the state of functions called between `G` and the call to panic is discarded, and normal execution resumes.

One thing to note here is that even if you call `panic()` in a deferred function, still all the other deferred functions will run. Also a `panic()` without `recover()` from a deferred function will rather "wrap" the existing panic and not "overwrite" it (although it's true that a `recover()` call will only give you back the value passed to the last `panic()` call).

See this example:

```
func main() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Checkpoint 1")
        panic(1)
    }()
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Checkpoint 2")
        panic(2)
    }()
    panic(999)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Eq5sdpNkDl)):

```
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 1
panic: 999
    panic: 2
    panic: 1

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0xfed00, 0x1040e140)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x720
main.main.func1()
    /tmp/sandbox284410661/main.go:8 +0x120
panic(0xfed00, 0x1040e0fc)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x8a0
main.main.func2()
    /tmp/sandbox284410661/main.go:12 +0x120
panic(0xfed00, 0x1040e0f8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x8a0
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox284410661/main.go:14 +0xc0
```

Even though all deferred functions call `panic()`, all deferred functions get executed, and the final panic sequence printed contains values passed to all `panic()` calls.

If you call `recover()` in the deferred functions, you also get this "recovered" state or info in the final printout:

```
defer func() {
    recover()
    fmt.Println("Checkpoint 1")
    panic(1)
}()
defer func() {
    recover()
    fmt.Println("Checkpoint 2")
    panic(2)
}()
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/r24bJOKJk3)):

```
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 1
panic: 999 [recovered]
    panic: 2 [recovered]
    panic: 1
...
```